# I can't rerender the array immediately when my array changes

Tags: reactjs

```
//this array update from onClick callback on button tag.
const [arrayLang, setArrayLang] = useState([]);

// this is element that i'll push
// this is update from onChange callback on select tag.
const [lang, setLang] = useState();

<div>
    <div>
        <h4>개발 언어</h4>
        {arrayLang.map((value, index)=>(
            <h5 key={index}>{value}</h5>
        ))}
    </div>
</div>
.
.
. 
<select 
    onChange={(value)=> {
    setLang(value.target.value);
                    
    setLang((lang)=>{
        console.log(lang);

        return lang
        })
    }}
>
.
.
.
</select>
<button onClick={()=>{
    let copiedLang = arrayLang;
    copiedLang.push(lang);
                    
    setArrayLang(copiedLang);

    setArrayLang((arrayLang) => {
        console.log(arrayLang);

        return arrayLang;
        })
    }}>추가</button>
```

the title is the content.

I checked the change about arrays,
the array is changed immediately, but the rendering side doesn't.
however, when I push the new element to the array, it renders the array that before I pushed.

e.g)

rendered array: (empty)

actual array : [1]

//if i push 2 to array

rendered array: 1

actual array: [1,2]

how do I render immediately when it changes?

++
[simple summary about my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgv3m.png)

i think the array has not problem with asynchronous.
what can i do?

Comment: Can you update more on how you work with useEffect or anything more in this situation, I think the problem is from there.

Comment: This probably has to do with `setState` being asynchronous, but you're not showing any code that would manipulate that state. Please add that code.